# can't see alerts - mvc5 with bootstrap via TempData

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

i tried to create  an alert so i could trigger a message if the user doesnt exist in the DB and redirect again to login view.
i tried few versions to popup a message and it was failure.
please your help.

i tried to use with scripts, and the scripts wont show up, i tried simple message .. nothing

//html

```
              <div>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                <br />
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <br />
                @if (TempData["Fail"] != null)
                {
                    <p class="alert alert" id="failMessage">
                        @TempData["Fail"]
                    </p>

                    <script>
                        alert(@TempData["Fail"]);
                    </script>
                }
            </div>
```

//controller

```
    UserDal userDal = new UserDal();
    List<User> dbUserList = userDal.users.Where(u => u.email.Equals(tempUser.email)).ToList();
    if (dbUserList.Count == 0)
    {

        //email dosent exist in db
        TempData["Fail"] = "Incorrect Detail Input";

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }
```

the actual results is a popup message (somewhere)...

Comment: <script>
   alert("@TempData['Fail']");
</script> not working also...

Comment: so you can print TempData in p tag but in alert not working?

Comment: also <p> tag not working..any possibility that bootstrap responsible for that?

Comment: put a debugger at if statement in your controller and debug it to see if you assign your error message to tempdata.

Comment: i'm ...inside the if statement of the DB results (i mean there was no results)

Comment: are you sure this html code is your index view?

Comment: yes. can you explain me how can i pass error message from controller to view ?

Comment: you can use tempdata.

Comment: I can t understand the problem with the code you showed. You can just put something to tempdata and display it in the view to test. Put your tempdata outside of if statement in the view and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

Change that part of your code like this:

```
<script>
   alert("@TempData['Fail']");
</script>
```